# how to add text every line in textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add text every line in textarea using:

```html
<textarea id="textarea1">text1


text2


text3


text4</textarea>

<textarea id="textarea2">one
two
three
four</textarea>

<button>process!</button>

Result:

text1 one


text2 two


text3 three


text4 four
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

You need to split the values from `/s` space to create an array out of the textbox values and loop it to append it.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var one = $.trim($('#textarea1').val()).split(' ');
  var two = $.trim($('#textarea2').val()).split(' ');

  $.each(one, function(i, v) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: v + ":" + two[i]
    }).appendTo('.result');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textarea1">
  text1 text2 text3 text4

</textarea>

<textarea id="textarea2">
  one two three four
</textarea>

<button>process!</button>
<div class='result'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing newline '`\n`' with '`<br />`', like:

```
var formattedString = yourString.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/j0ftouwd/ 
    OR Please check this one: `$('#textarea1').val("Hello\n\nTest");`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var result = $("#result");
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    var el = $.map($("textarea"), function(el, i) {
        return [$(el).text().split(/[\b\s]/).filter(Boolean)]
    });
    el[1].map(function(val, key) {
        return result.append("<br />" + el[0][key] + " " + val + "<br />")
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<textarea id="textarea1">text1


text2


text3


text4</textarea>

<textarea id="textarea2">one
two
three
four</textarea>

<button>process!</button>

<div id="result">
Result:
<!--
text1 one


text2 two


text3 three


text4 four
-->
</div>
```